# How can i pass more than one varible from a java activity to a javaclass?

Tags: java, android, openframeworks

I'm able to pass a string from a java activity to a class of librarie, but i can't figurate put how to send more than one i need to pass three here is the code:

OFActivity.java

```
package cc.openframeworks.androidMultiOFActivitiesExample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
import cc.openframeworks.OFAndroid;
import cc.openframeworks.androidMultiOFActivitiesExample.R.id;


public class OFActivityA extends cc.openframeworks.OFActivity{

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }


    OFAndroid of = new OFAndroid("jala");




}
```

OFAndroid.java

```
public class OFAndroid {


   private static String text ;

   public OFAndroid(String text) {
      this.text = text ;
   }


   public void useText() {
      Log.e("TAG" , this.text);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using a) Array, b) List, or c) Bundle

## Array

OFActivity.java

```java
public class OFActivityA extends cc.openframeworks.OFActivity{

    // onCreate()

    OFAndroid of = new OFAndroid(new String[]{"jala", "foo", "bar"});
}
```

OFAndroid.java

```java
public class OFAndroid {
   private String[] textArray ;

   public OFAndroid(String[] textArray) {
      this.textArray= textArray;
   }


   public void useText() {
      for (String text : textArray) {
          Log.e("TAG" , text);
      }
   }
```

## List

OFActivity.java

```java
public class OFActivityA extends cc.openframeworks.OFActivity{

    // onCreate()

    List<String> listOfString = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfString.add("jala");
    listOfString.add("foo");
    listOfString.add("bar");
    OFAndroid of = new OFAndroid(listOfString);
}
```

OFAndroid.java

```java
public class OFAndroid {
   private List<String> listOfString;

   public OFAndroid(List<String> listOfString) {
      this.listOfString = listOfString;
   }


   public void useText() {
      for (String text : listOfString) {
          Log.e("TAG" , text);
      }
   }
```

## Bundle

OFActivity.java

```java
public class OFActivityA extends cc.openframeworks.OFActivity{

    // onCreate()

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("keyOfString1", "jala");
    bundle.putString("keyOfString2", "foo");
    bundle.putString("keyOfString3", "bar");    
    OFAndroid of = new OFAndroid(bundle);
}
```

OFAndroid.java

```java
public class OFAndroid {
   private Bundle bundle ;

   public OFAndroid(Bundle bundle) {
      this.bundle = bundle;
   }

   public void useText() {
      Log.e("TAG", bundle.getString("keyOfString1")); // jala
      Log.e("TAG", bundle.getString("keyOfString2")); // foo
      Log.e("TAG", bundle.getString("keyOfString3")); // bar
   }
```

By the way, is there any reason to use static variable in OFAndroid.java?
It'll easily cause memory leak problems if you don't control the life cycle and reference of static Objects carefully.

Comment: Awesome, very helpull but i'm getting an error i will edit the post and paste the image. Thanks

Comment: @54555 I saw the picture of error in edit history. That error means your constructor of OFAndroid haven't refine to *OFAndroid(String[] textArray)*. Its constructor is still accepting String parameter like *OFAndroid(String text)*. This needs to be fixed first.

Comment: Just like the **OFAndroid.java** part in my answer of **Array**. See the line 4 in that.